# Email to case:Multiple cases for same email replies

Tags: email2case

In Email to case: New Case is getting created for the same email replies.Can we stop it and it should append it to same case in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use one of the following options (or both) in Email-to-Case setup.

- Insert Thread ID in the Email Subject
- Insert Thread ID in the Email Body

Comment: I am already using these options but its creating new case everytime for the same email.

Comment: After the first reply from Salesforce case, the email received on the other end sholud get populated with something like [ ref:_xxxxxxx._xxxxxxxxx:ref ] in subject line. 

Is that happening?

Comment: Actually i didnt replied to that email from Case object.so it was creating the new case everytime.Once i replied it added thread id and updated the same case.